# Can a gradient of continuous predicted and reference variables mean anything?

Tags: r, gradient, lm

I made an Random-Forest model with R to predict continuous target variable, and just encountered a problem with my customers. I was trying to tell them that RMSE is a good way to understand how good my model is, but they are asking me to give some "accuracy" like values with percentages to ease their understanding.

So what I have are vector of continuous predicted values and continuous actual value from my training set. what I tried are as following:

1. I got MAE values of two values instead, but they refused to take MAE (since it was not the answer they want like **% accuracy).
2. I generated correlation with two, got 0.80, and they didn't like it either.
3. I tried to factorize the predicted values but there was no way to rank my predicted value, and my accuracy with generated factor was just over 45%. No way they will take that.

So,

```
summary(lm(prediction~MAINDATA5_TEST_18FW$WEEK-1))

Call:
lm(formula = prediction ~ as.numeric(as.character(MAINDATA5_TEST_18FW$PLCWEEK)) - 
    1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6.8077 -1.1036  0.3121  1.6788  7.0615 

Coefficients:
                                                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
as.numeric(as.character(MAINDATA5_TEST_18FW$PLCWEEK)) 1.066786   0.006516   163.7   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.168 on 460 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9831,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9831 
F-statistic: 2.68e+04 on 1 and 460 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I tried the lm() formula to make more numbers and also told them R-squared between predicted and actual value is well above 0.98, which is pretty high. It was not enough to make them happy (again, they are obsessed with %s).

what caught my eye is the gradient, 1.066786. I was wondering that maybe I can say that model's predicted value is about 6.7% higher than the actual value on average. Is this interpretation reasonable enough? If these are all nonsense, then I will be very happy to get some suggestions too. Thanks..

Comment: This question is less about `r` code then interpreting your results / more of a stats question? SO is for specific questions, please try reading up on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In your case, since "your client is obsessed with %", couldn`t you just rework the R-squared into % (i.e. 98% of the variance...)?

Comment: Is it possible to bin your target variable and treat it as a classification problem? Just to get a accuracy measure you can show them.

Comment: I tried both solutions above, and it seemed like that was not the answer they wanted. in the end they agreed to round() the output and allow predicted values +/- 2 weeks, so I drew confusion matrix and added all predicted values within the 2 weeks range to generate accuracy.